# C#. Как спарсить текст со всеми совпадениями?

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
У меня к примеру есть такой текст:

```
-IP: 19283.123.12.3
-Contact As: ****@mail.ru
-Admin: admin

-IP: 123.12.312.31
-Contact As: ****@mail.ru
-Admin: admin

-IP: 23.11.23.123
-Contact As: ****@mail.ru
-Admin: admin
```

И к примеру я ввожу: "IP"
И программа должна мне выдать все совпадения
То есть вот так:

```
IP: 19283.123.12.3
IP: 123.12.312.31
IP: 23.11.23.123
```

Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: `foreach(var lines in File.ReadLines("myFile")){if (line.StartsWith("-IP")) Console.WriteLine(line)}` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Секунду, сейчас попробую

Comment: @tym32167 А если у меня текст уже из файла импортировался в textBox1?

Comment: `foreach (var lines in myTextBox.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)){ .... }`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо!!! заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
foreach(var lines in File.ReadLines("myFile"))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("-IP")) Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Вариант 2

```
foreach (var lines in myTextBox.Text
          .Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
{ .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно парсить при помощи Регулянных выражений:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```
string inputString =
    " - IP: 19283.123.12.3" +
    " - Contact As: ****@mail.ru" +
    " - Admin: admin" +
    "\n" +
    " - IP: 123.12.312.31" +
    " - Contact As: ****@mail.ru" +
    " - Admin: admin" +
    "\n" +
    " - IP: 23.11.23.123" +
    " - Contact As: ****@mail.ru" +
    " - Admin: admin";


var pattern = new Regex(@"IP: [\d]{1,}.[\d]{1,}.[\d]{1,}.[\d]{1,}");

string outputString = "";
foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(inputString))
{
    outputString += match.Value + "\n";
}
```

В результате значение outputString будет:

```
IP: 19283.123.12.3
IP: 123.12.312.31
IP: 23.11.23.123
```

Comment: Вероятно использовал не самый оптимальный паттерн.